# dfSummary - formatting factor levels in html output in Rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, summarytools

I'm trying to put together an html rmd report and having an issue with how `summarytools::dfSummary` displays factor levels. When I print to browser or R-Studio viewer, levels are formatted so that they are stacked vertically:

[image]

When I print to html in R Markdown they are formatted inline, which is annoying and less readable:

[image]

Any ideas on how to deal with this? I've looked around and haven't seen any way to deal with this in the `print()` function for `summarytools::`, maybe there's a way for me to reformat this in rmd?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe by narrowing the output width you can achieve to force Rmardown to display in column rather than line.. not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a day looking for a solution, so apparently summarytools’ CSS has been included in the following manner, with chunk option echo = FALSE:

` ``{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

st_css()

` ``